# How fix `octets is too long for type Varchar for column` in vetica via jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, vertica

There is a file (my_table.sql) and insert statement in it:

```
Insert into my_table (id, my_string) 
Values (1, 'some string with non ASCII symbols like this �');
```

Where I run this via jdbc it fails with `ERROR: String of N octets is too long for type Varchar(X) for column my_string`. And it looks like column is too short but when I run:

```
vsql -v AUTOCOMMIT=on  -h localhost -U dbadmin -d my_db < my_table.sql
```

It completes well. Why error happens? How to fix it? I have tried to add `?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` to jdbc connection string but this did not help.

UPDATED

Table definiton:

```
create table my_table
(
    id                      int,
    my_string               varchar(255)
);

comment on table my_table is 'copmment';
```

Comment: Two separate problems: column size and encoding. How is that table defined?

Comment: No column size problem because `vsql` works with same statement. Event more `insert` create from real DB and schemas for 2 DBs re the same. About table definition - nothing special. just create table. Question updated.

Comment: *..but when I run:* and what are the contents of that my_table.sql file?

Comment: did you solve this somehow?